# Can't connect to Flask REST API from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, rest, flask, fetch-api

I've tried to make a remote REST API using Flask and accessing it from JavaScript, but it doesn't work, it doesn't access the API and I don't know why, but when I enter the URL in browser I can see the results.
Here is my code:

Code from **init**.py found in directory:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
app = Flask(name)

api = Api(app)
@app.route("/")

def get_list():
    return ['some', 'strings']

class SomeClass(Resource):
    def get(self):
        value = get_list()
        return {'key': value}, 200

api.add_resource(SomeClass, '/users')
```

Code from run.py:

```
from directory import app

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)
```

And this is the code from JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function plzwork() {

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            body: '2',
            cache: 'no-cache'
        };

        fetch("<remote_public_IP>:<port>/", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
        //  .then(result => console.log(result))
        //  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    }</script>
```

Comment: did you try commenting out the .catch() to print the potential error?

Comment: yep. Nothing. :/

Comment: The question doesn’t show how the `plzwork()` function is defined, but it doesn’t show where the `plzwork()` function is being called. Is there code somewhere else that’s calling it? If not then maybe you just need to add a single line at the end of your existing code to call the function: `plzwork();`.

Comment: <li class="nav-item" onclick="plzwork()" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="UnassignedTasks.aspx"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i><span>All Tasks<br></span></a></li>

I guess it`s ok...

Comment: the network tab, does it say anything?

Comment: Nope :< I really don't know what to do in this case...

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not sure if your backend really works but here is the code with some changes:

Install `flask-cors` module:

```sh
pip install -U flask-cors
```

**Flask** -> `init.py` :

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS # + added

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # + added

api = Api(app)
@app.route("/") # you don't need this if you use Flask_restful
def get_list():
    return ['some', 'strings']

class SomeClass(Resource):
    def get(self):
        value = get_list()
        return {'key': value}, 200

api.add_resource(SomeClass, '/users')
```

`JavaScript` -> `body: '2'` were commented out:

```js
<script>
    function plzwork() {

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            // body: '2', 
            cache: 'no-cache'
        };
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
        //  .then(result => console.log(result))
        //  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    }
</script>
```

Your HTML (note the href tag I changed it to work for testing):

```html
<li class="nav-item" onclick="plzwork()" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/users">
<i class="fa fa-tasks"></i><span>All Tasks<br></span></a></li>
```

Combining HTML+JS for an easy implementation:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
<li class="nav-item" onclick="plzwork()" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/users">
<i class="fa fa-tasks"></i><span>All Tasks<br></span></a></li>


<script>
    function plzwork() {

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            cache: 'no-cache'
        };
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
        //  .then(result => console.log(result))
        //  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    }
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check your browser console.error ? I guess the problem is CORS, from your flask application, please enable CORS. Your can get it more [here](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: and when I search "<remote_public_IP>:<port>/" in browser it shows the data that has to be received by my javascript code...but in program I don`t receive anything

Comment: Could your following that link above. I guess it should work